# Swift hide view AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering how do I hide the view of the AVPlayer.

```swift
guard let url = URL(string: "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8006/stream.m3u") else {
  return
}
// Create a new AVPlayer and associate it with the player view
let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

// Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
controller.player = player

// Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
present(controller, animated: true) {
  player.play()
}
```

What I want to hide is the black screen it shows as this is just audio. No visual.

So I want to hide the viewer not necessarily the controlls.

Comment: Why would you need that by the way? Please clarify the context.

Comment: What are you expecting to be shown if it was hidden?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `AVPlayer` without `AVPlayerViewController` if you don't need the UI.

Comment: but how do I get it to play without AVPlayerViewController?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `AVPlayerViewController` to play an audio. You can create a view controller of your own and use `AVPlayer` with `AVPlayerLayer`.

```
let player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer()
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
YOUR_VIEW.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer) 

// Play the audio
let audioURL = URL(string: url)
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: audioURL)
player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
player.play()
```

You can hide `YOUR_VIEW` view if you'd like or display it if you are to play a video. It'd be better if `player` has a strong reference so I'd recommend storing it in a class variable. Also call `player.play()` on `AVPlayer.Status.readyToPlay` event of `AVPlayer`. You can learn more on [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayer)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the background color of the player

```
let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
controller.contentOverlayView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: that just makes the app not run - Value of optional type 'UIView?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'backgroundColor' of wrapped base type 'UIView'

Comment: contentOverlayView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white - that works

Comment: This gave you the behavior you want?

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want the UI like that of `AVPlayerViewController`, you can simply use `AVPlayerLayer` and add it as a `view's` `sublayer`.

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8006/stream.m3u") else {
    return
}

let player = AVPlayer(url: url)

let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = view.bounds
playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
playerLayer.contentsGravity = .resizeAspect
view.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 0)

player.play()
```

`AVPlayerLayer` will play the video same as `AVPlayerViewController`.

Also, you can add the `playerLayer` to any view's layer. Be it main view or any custom view.

For more you can refer the link - https://medium.com/free-code-camp/how-to-set-up-video-streaming-in-your-app-with-avplayer-7dc21bb82f3